# Creating prediction grid within certain boundary for surface interpolation in R?

Tags: polygon, r, overlay, grids-graticules, borders

I am trying to create a prediction grid within my boundary polygon.

Firstly I need to make sure that my boundary shapefile is in UTM coordinates:

```
 NZGD <- CRS("+init = epsg: 2193")
```

Load my file:

```
boundary <- readOGR(dsn = "C:\\Users\\gjiang\\Documents", layer = "boundary")
border <- spTransform(boundary,NZGD)
plot(border, axes=TRUE, main="Projected", cex.axis=.95)
```

The file has been converted and the plot looks ok.

So I start to create a prediction grid:

```
vals <- border@bbox
deltaLong <- as.integer((vals[1,2]-vals[1,1])+1.5)
deltaLat <- as.integer((vals[2,2]-vals[2,1])+1.5)
gridRas <- 5
gridSizeX <- deltaLong/gridRas
gridSizeY <- deltaLat/gridRas
grd <- GridTopology(vals[,1],c(gridRas,gridRas),c(gridSizeX,gridSizeY))

pts <- SpatialPoints(coordinates(grd))
pts1<- SpatialPointsDataFrame(as.data.frame(pts),data=as.data.frame(rep(1,nrow(as.data.frame(pts)))))
proj4string(pts1) <- CRS("+init=epsg:2193")
```

Check the results:

```
plot(pts)
plot(pts1)
```

They show me the entire grid!

It also turns out error in the following step:

```
pts1$border = over(pts1, border) 

# Error: identicalCRS(x, y) is not TRUE
```

Can anyone tell what have I done wrong?

Comment: Zone 60's center is not at 173, but at 177. Oh, you're using NZGD2000 / NZTM (EPSG:2193). The first definition of UTM60H is just wrong. What coordinate system is the original data in? Could it already be in 2193?

Comment: Instead of hard coding in the proj string why not just use the epsg identifier? `spTransform(boundary, CRS("+init=epsg:3707"))` Also, it appears that you are not setting your CRS for `pts1` but you are for `border`. That's what's probably giving you your indenticalCRS error. What does `pts1@coords` return?

Comment: pts1@coords returns `num[1:145672, 1:2] 1792240 1792245 1792250 ...` I've tried `proj4string(pts1) <- CRS("+init=epsg:2193")` before `pts1<-` but it still shows the entire grid @JMT_2080AD

Comment: The original data is in wgs84 so I use spTransform() to change it to NZTM (EPSG:2193). @mkennedy

Comment: Can you make your boundary accessible?

Comment: I can plot my boundary `plot(border, axes=TRUE, main="Projected", cex.axis=.95)` so that's no a problem. @dof1985

Comment: @GoldenJiang sorry for being unclear. I meant, can you upload your boundary layer somewhere in order to make your problem reproducible?

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/c7b0wm0lcdt0biu/AACakt02hVlwuaVzM113WgSKa?dl=0  Thanks, just upload the files to dropbox @dof1985

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I`m not quite sure what you are trying to achieve with

> `pts1$border = over(pts1, border)`

or with

> `pts1 <- SpatialPointsDataFrame(as.data.frame(pts), data = as.data.frame(rep(1, nrow(as.data.frame(pts)))))`

Anyhow `plot(pts1)` shows the full-grid since you havn't done anything to prevent this. You have defined its `bbox` as the original `boundaries` extent. As such, it fills all the extent with `SpatialPoints`.

It think that what you were looking for is the following:

> `plot(pts1, axes = TRUE, col = colors()[6])
>   pts2 <- pts1[border, ]
>   plot(pts2, axes = TRUE, add = TRUE)`

The `pts2 <- pts1[border, ]` clips the points layer using the polygon. See [this blog](http://robinlovelace.net/r/2014/07/29/clipping-with-r.html) about clipping spatial data with R. The image below show the result: `pts2` shown in black over the original full extent `pts1` in sort-of grey.

[image: Result]

Comment: What is the difference between `SpatialPointsDataFrame` and `SpatialPoints`? Does `SpatialPoints` only contain coordinates, not z values?@dof1985

Comment: That's right. `SpatialPointDataFrame` is a wrapper for both `SpatialPoints` with coordinates, and a `data.frame` with attributes.  Yet that is another question. It is better to stick to one question a thread. With regards to your question the answer focuses on the subset function `[`, namely this line: `pts2 <- pts1[border, ]`

Answer (score 0):

Make sure `newdfNoNAs` is in `SpatialPointsDataFrame`, it is probably easier to use `sp` package:

```
 library(sp)
 grd = spsample(newdfNoNAs, type = "regular",n=10000)
 pts <- grd[border,]
 plot(pts, axes = TRUE)
```